# QR Codes, not sure if they are working on Blackberries

Tags: blackberry, qr-code

quick question I made some qr codes and they work fine on my iPhone when I tested them, but apparently they dont work on blackberries...not sure why.

Here is the link to my qr code

http://sandysmallbone.com/mobile/qr/URL/URLExtraLarge.png

I know the person who is trying to test it out on a blackberry and they are kinda slow minded, which is making me think they are doing something wrong and my codes work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is the meaning of these lines in your post: "I know the person who is trying to test it out on a blackberry and they are kinda slow minded"; Give the reply urgent;

Comment: It's an English idiom that means they are not smart / computer savy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it on my Android phone and from this [website](http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx). I got the following hex code

```
42 06 87 47 47 03 a2 f2 f7 36 16 e6 47 97 36 d6 16 c6 c6 26 f6 e6 52 e6 36 f6 d2 f6 d6 f6 26 96 c6 50 c6 50
```

Which resulted it being flagged as a URI for

http://sandysmallbone.com/mobile

So based on the fact that your iPhone, the website, and my Android ( HTC Incredible ) all parsed it successfully I would imagine it is correct.

UPDATE:

I also just tested it on my co-worker's Blackberry and it worked as well

Comment: Thanks Halfwarr...so I am not crazy someone is just not scanning it properly?

Comment: From what I can tell, on the devices I tested it worked fine. Maybe have them try a different QR Reader Program?

Comment: @user1193385: In your point of view we are not that much of good, you are the only good; I did the Barcode application which is scanning any type of Barcode format and generate qrcode image and Decode all types of formats without scanning; What is the meaning of these lines in your post: "I know the person who is trying to test it out on a blackberry and they are kinda slow minded"....?